# Rearrange name formats in notepad++ using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a list of name separated by comma and the format of name is Surname followed by first name and middle name like this

**Parameshwar S, Goutami, Patil D B**

and i want to use regex to find and replace so that my output will as follow as first name middle name and last name **S Parameshwar, Goutami, D B Patil**

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working, and what is the erroneous result? Look up a basic tutorial on using **capture groups** in regex replace operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find with regex `([a-zA-Z]+) +([a-zA-Z][^\n\r,]*)(?=$|,)` and replace with `\2 \1`

https://regex101.com/r/qH6rL9/2 to see the result.

In brief, here is what the regex is doing

`([a-zA-Z]+)`: (Group 1) a bunch of alphabets
`+`: follow by at least one space
`([a-zA-Z][^\n\r,]*)`: (Group 2) follow by something start with alphabet which then follow by non-newlines-non-commas
`(?=$|,)`: until you meet a position either is end of line, or a comma

Group 1 is the Surname, Group 2 is the rest of name.

Comment: nice regex and usage

Comment: A little update. Seems Notepad++ may match newlines with `[^,]+`, and the capture group in the last look-ahead group is actually redundant.  I have updated the answer slighty